# WSO2 Identity Server 6.0 unable to find API for retrieve and update challenge questions

Tags: wso2-identity-server

1.We are adding the security questions in /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection. We are trying to retrieve those using /me/challenges GET method under Challenge Questions API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/, but we are not able to retrieve them and also update them using GET and PUT API's. Is there any way to retrieve these questions which are added under this directory/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection and also update them??

Comment: What is the response you receive for GET `https://<host>:<port>/api/users/v1/me/challenges`  without any update?

Answer (score 1):

As per the description, seems you want to manage the question sets and their questions stored in the server.

Use the following REST APIs to retrieve the question sets stored in `/_system/config/identity/questionCollection` location and update those question sets.

https://github.com/wso2/identity-api-server/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.api.server.challenge/org.wso2.carbon.identity.rest.api.server.challenge.v1/src/main/resources/challenge.yaml

GET challenge questions grouped by question set id:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://localhost:9443/api/server/v1/challenges' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
```

Update questions in one set:
eg: PUT request to replace all questions in challengeQuestion2 set

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://localhost:9443/api/server/v1/challenges/challengeQuestion2' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: */*' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--data-raw '[
    {
        "locale": "en_US",
        "question": "Name of the hospital where you were born ?",
        "questionId": "question2"
    },
    {
        "locale": "en_US",
        "question": "Model of your first car ?",
        "questionId": "question1"
    }
]'
```

eg: PATCH request to ADD one question to challengeQuestion2 set

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://localhost:9443/api/server/v1/challenges/challengeQuestion2' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: */*' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--data-raw '{
  "operation": "ADD",
  "challengeQuestion": {
    "question": "what is your school",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "questionId": "question9"
  }
}'
```

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/ this REST API is used to manage the challenge questions answers. `/me/challenges` and `/{user-id}/challenges` APIs are there to list out what are the available questions for the user to answer.

Comment: We are trying to add/update/retrieve the questions located in this directory (directory/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection) and not in (/_system/config/identity/questionCollection) location

Comment: Can you mention the steps that you follow to add questions to that particular location

Comment: We have created local claims (http://wso2.org/claims/challengeQuestion1) and using those claims in challenge management and now we want to retrieve/update those claims from rest api's

Comment: http://wso2.org/claims/challengeQuestion1 claim of a user stores the selected challenge question from the challenge question set 1 and the given answer for that. As I see `/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection` location contains the initial 8 question questions added by the server by default. but all the security question management will happen based on the stored question in `/_system/config/identity/questionCollection`. could you please clearly mention the steps you followed to add questions to the mentioned location?

Comment: /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection location has question0 to question7 (8 question resources) but those will not be updated. All question updates are managing at /_system/config/identity/questionCollection location

Comment: 1.First we changed the questionSetId mentioned in (/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection) like for question0- challengeQuestion1, question1-challengeQuestion2 and so on...we changed upto 8 questions.2. Then under claims section we added local claims by clicking on add button, there we have given claim uri's (wso2.org/claims/challengeQuestion1) and mapped attribute (first) and so on upto 8 questions. 3.Now we are trying to retrieve/update these questions.  Is there any way of retrieving/updating these questions using rest API?

Comment: It's bit hard to understand what you have done. If you need the user to be answered for 8 questions, then you need to have 8 question sets. I have mentioned the REST API to manage those question sets. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/managing-challenge-questions/#managing-challenge-questions Here is the doc for question set management. It would be easier to solve if you mention the exact use case that you are trying to achieve

Comment: As you said, security question management will happen based on the stored question in /_system/config/identity/questionCollection, can't we able to retrieve the security questions stored in security question management will happen based on the stored question in /_system/config/identity/questionCollection?

Comment: Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73997306/10055162