# WSO2 IS - Difference between Story Challenge Questions on /identity/questionCollection VS org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Want to understand the difference between storing challenge questions in WSO2 as showing below. **Which approach is good, which one is recommended and respective APIs?**

**Which scenario the below approaches are followed?**

[image]

**1. Approach One -** Storing challenge questions in **org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection** as shown below.

> **/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection**

[image]

**Expectations-**

**- Share the list of REST APIs for the above questions**
**- Is this approach is available in WSO2 IS 6.0.0?**

**2. Approach Two-** Storing challenge questions in **identity/questionCollection** as shown below.
**

> /_system/config/identity/questionCollection

**
[image]

**Expectations-**

**- Share the list of REST APIs for the above questions**

Answer (score 0):

1. I experienced that challenge questions stored at `/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection` are managed by `UserIdentityManagementAdminService`. It's `setChallengeQuestions` service is used to set the questions for the server. `getAllChallengeQuestions` serviced is used to retrieve the questions stored at this location. Using `setChallengeQuestionsOfUser` service we can set challenge questions and answers for each user and the questions are taken from this location.
   I'm exactly not sure about the reason for having challenge questions on this location and challenge question management services available in `UserIdentityManagementAdminService`.

- Anyway, there is **no REST API** to set/ retrieve the challenge
  questions maintained in the
  `/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection`
  location.

2. If you were using SOAP APIs ChallengeQuestionManagementAdminService is the expected admin service to be used in order to manage the challenge question of the server which are stored in `/_system/config/identity/questionCollection` location and set challenge questions for the user.

- If you used the management console UI
  https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/managing-challenge-questions/#adding-a-challenge-question-set
  to configure challenge questions of the server /
  ChallengeQuestionManagementAdminService admin service it should
  update the questions in `/_system/config/identity/questionCollection`
  location.
- https://github.com/wso2/identity-api-server/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.api.server.challenge/org.wso2.carbon.identity.rest.api.server.challenge.v1/src/main/resources/challenge.yaml this is the corresponding REST API to manage the challenge questions in the server. (In other words, this REST API manages the question stored at `/_system/config/identity/questionCollection`
  location.) refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73870503/10055162
- https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/#/ This REST API is used to get the available questions in the server that a user can answer for, set the challenge question answers to selected question y user and retrieved the answers of the answered questions.

If you were using the questions stored in `/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection` location, and now you need to use REST API in IS-6.0.0, its better to move the questions to the correct place using https://github.com/wso2/identity-api-server/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.api.server.challenge/org.wso2.carbon.identity.rest.api.server.challenge.v1/src/main/resources/challenge.yaml t API/ management console according to the current questions' `questionSetId`

[image]